# setText ("" + REG1); ошибка: при нажатии на кнопку приложение выключается

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
int REG1 = 10;
TextView N1;
```

---

```
public void onclick(View view){
      N1.setText(" " + REG1);
}
```

Comment: а что в логах пишется? какая именно ошибка?

Comment: Я нажимаю на кнопку которая должна вывести "REG1" в TextView который я назвал N1 но при нажатии на кнопку приложение выключается

Comment: у вас в android studio есть вкладка внизу - logcat, откройте ее и посмотрите на какой строке ошибка.

Comment: а ошибку какую выдает?

Comment: скорее всего вы не инициализировали TextView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы похоже не нашли `TextView`, а пытаетесь обратиться к `null` объекту.

```
public void onclick(View view){
      N1 = findViewById(R.id.idOfYourN1TextView); //подставьте необходимый id
      N1.setText(" " + REG1);
}
```

Comment: Вместо вашей второй строки написал это "N1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.N1);" всё теперь работает, я где-то в своём коде двумя чертами отделил эту строку

Comment: просто с 26 версии API, нет необходимости кастовать, поэтому так и написал